# Examples for "Use app first, register later"?

Tags: usability

I'm looking for web applications that users can use without registration, just by visiting the site, and make you register later after you spent some time.

Any good examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when you are looking for example sites that you've seen in the past, it is just to increase your own confidence that you are doing it right.  If you have a good idea of the advantages of this style of progressive registration, why not take a moment to write down & plan out how  it should work for your site?

Edit content without registration (but create a pseudo-account using IP address):

- wikipedia

Register with your email address, optionally password protect your account later:

- http://www.instapaper.com/

Registration as a side effect of paying for a product

- Amazon (if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow; **question an answer sites**.

Google News; **blogs and newsfeeds**.

Apple's iTunes Store, Amazon; **anything where you have a shopping cart**.

Answer (score 1):

:-)

There's this site called StackOverflow.com